# Keyboard special function keys don't work over Bluetooth

Tags: release-loki, keyboard, bluetooth

I've paired an Apple Magic Keyboard 2 with my Dell E7470 running elementaryOS Loki and the secondary function keys don't work. Strangely, when connected over USB they work perfectly fine (though it needs a few remappings). I've re-paired several times and even manually using `bluetoothctl`.

Holding down the `fn` key makes no difference. I've also verified by running `xev` in terminal that I can't get the special keys events to trigger, they always register as the F{number} keys.

I'm curious if there's something that I'm missing, like a driver perhaps, or could it be just incompatible?

`sudo evtest` results on the `/dev/input/eventX` for the keyboard over USB:

```
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x5ac product 0x267 version 0x110
Input device name: "Apple Inc. Magic Keyboard"
....
Event code 204 (KEY_DASHBOARD)
Event code 208 (KEY_FASTFORWARD)
Event code 224 (KEY_BRIGHTNESSDOWN)
Event code 225 (KEY_BRIGHTNESSUP)
Event code 227 (KEY_SWITCHVIDEOMODE)
Event code 228 (KEY_KBDILLUMTOGGLE)
Event code 229 (KEY_KBDILLUMDOWN)
Event code 230 (KEY_KBDILLUMUP)
Event code 240 (KEY_UNKNOWN)
Event code 464 (KEY_FN)
```

And the keyboard over Bluetooth with the above event codes no where to be found:

```
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x5 vendor 0x4c product 0x267 version 0x66
Input device name: "Magic Keyboard"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working over Bluetooth by building the latest Kernel after applying this patch, https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=99881#c41